# What is httpContext.Response.SubStatusCode for?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, response, httpcontext

What is `httpContext.Response.SubStatusCode` for? this value is part of the IIS integration mode pipeline.

Comment: I will. just taking a small brake... :)

Comment: btw, it would be great if you'll help me answer them all... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substatus is a category within the main status code which provides a little more information about the nature of the condition raising the main status code.

For example, error 401 (unauthorised) has several substatus codes:

401.1 - Logon failed.
401.2 - Logon failed due to server configuration.
401.3 - Unauthorized due to ACL on resource.
401.4 - Authorization failed by filter.
401.5 - Authorization failed by ISAPI/CGI application.

The full reference for HTTP status and substatus codes in IIS 7 is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891)

Answer (score 0):

It gives you status code of the http response.
For more details check [HttpResponse.SubStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.substatuscode.aspx)  and [Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/)

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I sew this links before asking.